# Bridged networking is unreliable on VMWare Fusion running Windows 7

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion

I am running Windows 7 under VMWare Fusion on Snow Leopard, connecting to my router via Airport.

When I select "Share the Mac's network connection (NAT)" under the Network options, everything works fine.

But I want the Windows VM to have its own, externally visible, IP Address, so I choose "bridged", and now the internet doesn't work in the VM, or takes ages to find sites, and drops connections sporadically.

Anything I should be doing? Is this an Airport-related problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actuallly, seems like my router was the problem.

I am based in London, using a very recent 2-wire "business broadband" router from BT. Because it doesn't do Wifi "n" (only b/g) I have a Time Capsule bridged to it which serves as my Wifi node.

Seems either the 2-wire or the time capsule don't like VM Ware bridged mode, since I have another wifi connection (Virgin cable) and that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Internet Sharing turned on? (Even if it's not being used, just enabled).  That can cause problems with bridged mode in VMWare Fusion.   I was experiencing something similar, turned off Internet Sharing (wasn't actively using it anyways) and the problem went away.

Comment: No Tim - internet sharing is turned off.